# Convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{p} \ln(n)^{2}}$ for $p>0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am attempting to test the convergence for the following series for a final review:
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{p} \ln(n)^{2}}, p>0$$
My classmates and I have tested the convergence for when $p=1$ and $p>1$; the series converges in both cases (Comparison Test). However, we are having problems for when $0<p<1$. Was wondering if we could get some hints for this third case.

Comment: Your series in the title differs from that in the question. In the exponent on $\ln(n)$ equal to $p$ or $2$?

Comment: I that  (\log n )^2 ,that is, $(\log n)^2$ ? Or \log (n^2), that is, $\log (n^2)$ ?

Comment: Hint: Cauchy Condensation Test.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On convergence of Bertrand series $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}\ln^{\beta}(n)}$ where $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2563446/on-convergence-of-bertrand-series-sum-limits-n-2-infty-frac1n-alpha) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1264767/infinite-sum-of-dfrac1np-lnnq).

Answer (score 1):

Edit: this answer addresses the original question, $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^p\ln(n)^p}$.

The series diverges when $p=1$ by the integral test.

When $0<p<1$, using the fact that
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{x^a}=0 $$
for any $a>0$, we have
$$ n^p\ln(n)^p\leq n^pn^{ap}=n^{p(a+1)}$$
for all sufficiently large $n$ (depending on $a$). Choosing $a>0$ small enough that $p(a+1)<1$, it follows that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{p(a+1)}}$ diverges, and since
$$ \frac{1}{n^p\ln(n)^p}\geq \frac{1}{n^{p(a+1)}} $$
for all large enough $n$, this shows that $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^p\ln(n)^p}$ diverges as well.

Comment: Alternately, once you have the divergence for $p=1$ you can just use the comparison test against that series for $p\lt 1$.

Comment: Good point, that works too.

Comment: I apologize, but there was an error when I was transcribing the problem.

Comment: If the series is the series stated in the question (not the one in the title) then the series converges when $p=1$ (and the Integral Test can show that).

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^p\ln(n)^2}$$ then take the integral $$\int_2^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^p\ln(x)^2}\,dx$$ and make the substitution $u=\ln(x)$ to get $$\int_{\ln(2)}^{\infty}\frac{1}{e^{(p-1)u}u^2}\,du$$
If $p<1$, then the integrand itself approaches $\infty$ as $u\to\infty$, so the integral diverges. So the series would diverge for $p<1$ by the Integral Test.